# Redirect active FTP traffic to another server using iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp, redirect, port-forwarding, vsftpd

[Network Scheme - IP addresses are fictitious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv4V9.png)

**Firewall SO: Centos 6**

I recently enabled two-factor authentication, using Google Authenticator, and with that transfers via SCP for some users were impossible to carry out. So the solution I found was to transfer files via FTP (active), using VSFTP (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).
I am using active FTP due to strict network restrictions at my university (passive FTP is not allowed).
I was able to successfully redirect the SSH access to the server. However, I am having difficulties with FTP. I've already tried several rules, and read a lot of documentation and tips on forums.

****Firewall.** Open ports:**

- 22/TCP, 2222/TCP, 65020/TCP, 65021/TCP.

**Internal server. Open ports:**

- 20/TCP, 21/TCP, 22/TCP.

Requests received on port 22/TCP to access the firewall via SSH.

Requests received on port 2222/TCP on the firewall are redirected to port 22/TCP (SSH) on the internal server.

Requests received on port 65020/TCP on the firewall are redirected to port 20/TCP (FTP-DATA) on the internal server.

Requests received on port 65021/TCP on the firewall are redirected to port 21/TCP (FTP) on the internal server.

The following are the firewall IPTABLES rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65020 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65021 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65020 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:20
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65021 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:21
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Port 2222/TCP redirect works perfectly. I can access the internal server via SSH. Access via FTP is not working. I get the following message from Filezilla:

> Status:   Connecting to 172.17.1.212:65021... Status: Connection
> established, waiting for welcome message... Status:   Insecure server,
> it does not support FTP over TLS. Status: Server does not support
> non-ASCII characters. Status: Logged in Status:   Retrieving directory
> listing... Command:   PWD Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
> Command:  TYPE I Response:    200 Switching to Binary mode. Command:  PORT
> 172,17,1,253,233,145 Response:    500 Illegal PORT command. Command:  PASV
> Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,2,56,33). Command: LIST
> Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
> Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing

I've tried other rules, but I won't put them here because I don't want to clutter up the post with unnecessary information.

The "nf_conntrack_ftp" module is loaded.

```
# lsmod | grep ftp
nf_conntrack_ftp       12081  0 
nf_conntrack           79761  7 nf_conntrack_ftp,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
```

The IPV4 forwarding is loaded too:

```
# sysctl -p | grep "net.ipv4.ip_forward"
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**FTP access via the internal network works fine (I use Filezilla's active mode option).**

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

My best regards.

Comment: "are redirected to port 20/TCP (FTP-DATA) " that's not how FTP works. The data flow connection is initiated as outgoing port 20 on server to client. Not from client to server. This doesn't matter for a stateless firewall (hence so many blogs telling to open port 21 + port 20: this is already a comprehension mistake), but does at least for NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to active FTP mode, it use separate connection for control and data which can cause issue with your `iptables` rules.

first set a range of ports in `vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=50100
```

then restart

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

then open the proper port range `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000:50100 -j ACCEPT`

then we redirect the `ports` for FTP data connections from your firewall to your internal server

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000:50100 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

then finaly configure `Filezilla` to use `passive` mode instead of `active` mode, then it should work.

Comment: I did it, but is not woking.
I changed the ports on vsftp:
 listen_port=65021
 ftp_data_port=65020
And I changed the rules (just to be the same ports):
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65020 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:65020 
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65021 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:65021 
...
I will try to resolve this.